# Extract function pointer arguments and return types

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to find a way to extract the type and number of arguments and return type function pointer so I can write something like this:

```
int foo(int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;
}

template<class T, class U>
U callfunc(T, ...);

int main()
{
    int k = callfunc(&foo, 3, 5);
}
```

`callfunc` will check if the number of arguments and the types are correct and return the result. But how should it be implemented?

I've googled a bit and found some articles covering similar topics using macros and templates but still can't do it.

Can someone provide some pointers?

Thanks!

P.S: I can't use variadic templates because VS2012 doesn't support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want some variadic templates, something like:

```
template<typename TResult, typename ...TArgs>
TResult callfunc(TResult (*fn)(TArgs...), TArgs... args)
{
   /* do something with the args, if you wanted */
   TResult result = fn(std::forward(args)...);
   /* do something to the return value, if you wanted */
   return std::forward(result);
}
```

Comment: VS2012 doesn't have support for variadic templates... Is there another way to do it?

Comment: @TiagoCosta: I'm pretty sure not any other nice way.  I believe that the VS2012 team emulated variadic templates by using macros to create a whole bunch of function overloads with different number of arguments.  I'll try to find some of the related blog posts and see if there's an example you can copy.

Comment: [Here it is](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx)  Take a look at `shared` and `xxshared` header files, to see the fake-variadic macros in action for `std::make_shared`, which is forwarding almost exactly like your example, except that it forwards to a constructor instead of a free function.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it. Using variadic templates like in your answer what prevents me from passing a wrong number of arguments or incorrect types? I was hoping to have some `if`s in there...

Comment: @Tiago: Note that `TArgs` appears inside the function pointer type and also inside the extra arguments.  The compiler will force them to match.